# Translate simple code with C#6 syntax to Vb.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, syntax, code-translation

Someone could help me to translate this simple snippet that uses the new C# 6 syntax, to Vb.Net?

The resulting LINQ query is incomplete (wrong syntax) when doing a translation in some online services like one from **[Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)**.

```
/// <summary>
///     An XElement extension method that removes all namespaces described by @this.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="this">The @this to act on.</param>
/// <returns>An XElement.</returns>
public static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(this XElement @this)
{
    return new XElement(@this.Name.LocalName,
        (from n in @this.Nodes()
            select ((n is XElement) ? RemoveAllNamespaces(n as XElement) : n)),
        (@this.HasAttributes) ? (from a in @this.Attributes() select a) : null);
}
```

Comment: Reflector v9 does a very decent job decompiling this to VB.  Just get your own copy.

Comment: This might work. [Convert Code](http://converter.telerik.com/) or get you pretty close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function RemoveAllNamespaces(this As XElement) As XElement
    Return New XElement(this.Name.LocalName,
        (From n In this.Nodes
         Select (If(TypeOf n Is XElement, TryCast(n, XElement).RemoveAllNamespaces(), n))),
        If((this.HasAttributes), (From a In this.Attributes Select a), Nothing))
End Function
```

In case you'll be converting other code, here's the steps I took:

- Added the `Extension` attribute, because VB does not have syntax like C# does for creating extension methods.
- Replaced the C# ternary operator with VB `If(condition, true, false)`.
- Replaced C# casts with VB `TryCast(object, type)`.
- Replaced C# type checking with VB `TypeOf object Is type`.
- Replaced C# `null` with VB `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

Including the xml comments, and correcting the 'RemoveAllNamespaces' error in the other answer, your VB equivalent is:

```
''' <summary>
'''     An XElement extension method that removes all namespaces described by @this.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="this">The @this to act on.</param>
''' <returns>An XElement.</returns>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Function RemoveAllNamespaces(ByVal this As XElement) As XElement
    Return New XElement(this.Name.LocalName, (
        From n In this.Nodes()
        Select (If(TypeOf n Is XElement, RemoveAllNamespaces(TryCast(n, XElement)), n))),If(this.HasAttributes, (
            From a In this.Attributes()
            Select a), Nothing))
End Function
```